# High Memory utilisation in windows Server2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have Server 2012 R2 with 160 GB Of RAM and nearly 100 users are working on it..Mozilla and google chrome is using all memory so is it any solution for that bcz my serve is running at 100%CPU and memory utilization.

Comment: Thank u guys for your reply... Actually I have 4TB SSD and 160gb RAM with 100 users working on RDP. Do you guys think that for improve performance of server I should need to switch from balance power supply to High Performance option.

Answer (score 3):

Well, what about some simple math?

160GB / 100 users. That is an amazing 1.6GB per user (ignoring the fact that the OS neds some space too, as do you need video memory) I find less than 1.5gb (after deducting the overheads) extremely pathetic - phones and small tablets have more.

What do you expect? That just because you use remote desktop/teminal server (which is the only way your queston makes any sense, though you do not consider this to be some data to give us) they will magically not use memory?

Get more ram. For your user load, 160gb are not enough.

Comment: Hopefully they have thin clients. Otherwise it would be even more sad to see 100 employees work on 1.5G RAM while their RDP client probably has more RAM in it.

Comment: Thank u guys for your reply... Actually I have 4TB SSD and 160gb RAM with 100 users working on RDP. Do you guys think that for improve performance of server I should need to switch from balance power supply to High Performance option.